# Handle UITapGestureRecognizer in another UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to handle a gesture in another UIViewController, but the program crashes. I want to invoke the handleTap function in the Second UIViewController.

This is what I want to do but it crashes (Error Message: unrecognized selector sent to class):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad()
        Second.showMenu(self)
    }

}

public class Second: UIViewController {

    static func showMenu(_ vc: ViewController) {

        let bgView = UIView(frame: vc.view.frame)
        vc.view.addSubview(bgView)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.handleTap(sender:)))
        bgView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        bgView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }

    func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("handleTap")
    }

}
```

This works, but I want to be able to handle everything in the Second UIViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad()
        Second.showMenu(self)
    }

    func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("handleTap")
    }

}

public class Second: UIViewController {

    static func showMenu(_ vc: ViewController) {

        let bgView = UIView(frame: vc.view.frame)
        vc.view.addSubview(bgView)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: vc, action:#selector(vc.handleTap(sender:)))
        bgView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        bgView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function:

```
static func showMenu(_ vc: ViewController) {}
```

Is a static function. It means that it's not executed on a instance of the view controller, but on the class itself. You added a gesture recognizer:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.handleTap(sender:)))
```

*target:self* means that the selector is invoked on the class, but the *handleTap* function is not static. An easy workaround would be to make it a static function:

```
static func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("handleTap")
}
```

But I think that it still doesn't make sense, even if it works. I can hardly imagine a situation where you need to execute a selector as response of an event generated in another view controller.

Comment: I'm presenting a custom view on the main view and I want to handle all the code in another class, so my code is more modular. The view I'm presenting is going to have a menu, then the user can tap the "background", which will be the view, to dismiss a small menu in the center of the view (if that makes sense). Anyway, Thank you! Can tell me where I can learn this concept?

Comment: @Joe Then I suggest to add an empty implementation of handleTap(:) in ViewController, and make Second a subclass of ViewController. So if you have an instance of Second, the overrided version of the method will be automatically called, otherwise the empty implementation will be called.